# making external references stick out

Tags: cross-referencing

I am splitting some text into several files, so there are external references. These I would like to emphasize in some way, for printing, like: "theorem 7 (from OtherPaper)". Since there is a lot of such references, and the splitting is not stable, I would like an automatic way to achieve this. What I have so far is:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[hypertex]{hyperref} 
\begin{document}
\def\ifUnDefinedCs#1{\expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax}  %Victor Eijkhout, "TeX by Topic", p.143
\newcommand{\myautoref}[1]{\ifUnDefinedCs{r@#1} {\pending{#1}}\else\autoref{#1}\fi}
\newcommand{\pending}[1]{\color{red}\autoref{#1} from "file.tex"}
% \externaldocument{file}[../file]  %(A)
Using \myautoref{sec:vis} and \myautoref{sec:vis},...
% \externaldocument{file}[../file]  %(B)
\end{document}
```

As soon as `\externaldocument{file}[../file]` is issued, all labels in `file.aux` are added immediately, if I got that right. So if line (A) is used, the references upon them shall not "look any different" in print than any local references. If line (B) is used, the labels are added kinda too late, and repeated compilation does not change anything.
My question: Is there a possibility to enforce a "second pass", i.e. activate extraneous labels *after* their references have been marked?

Comment: Do you use a bibliography?

Comment: yes, but what is your drift?

Comment: If you cite document from other paper that are in your bibliography, you can use `\cite[Theorem 7]{OtherPaper}` to make the ref you want. Does correspond to what you want?

Comment: well thank you, I didn't know that, but it does not quite solve the problem: I would like \myautoref{lem:bigdeal} uniformly in the documents, independant of actual theorem names/numbers and of actual splitting

Comment: If you want only to reference from other LaTeX file perhaps the xr package is what you need.

Comment: xr-hyper is loaded above, and it provides adequate referencing/hyperlinking, but the *print* form is indistinguishable from local references. I would like the external references to *stick out* in print form.

Comment: @ave: Have a look on my proposition please

Comment: sorry to have kept you waiting, I had to go offline, but more importantly: yes, that is nice and simple, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure this is what the O.P. requests: The `xr` package allows to specifiy a label prefix for the external document, say `A-`.

It's necessary (in my point of view) to check first whether this `\r@A-#2` command exists at all, if this is not the case, the reference is considered to be a local one and `\autoref{...}` is used then.

By the way: `\ifUnDefinedCs` is not necessary, since the LaTeX core provides `\@ifundefined{}{}{}` already.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}

\usepackage{hyperref} 

\externaldocument[A-]{extfile}  %(A)
\makeatletter

\newcommand{\myautoref}[2][A-]{%
  \@ifundefined{r@#1#2}{% Nope A-#2 isn't there
    \@ifundefined{r@#2}{%
    }{%
      \autoref{#2}%
    }%
  }{%
    {\pending{#1#2}}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\pending}[1]{\color{red}\autoref{#1} from "file.tex"}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
Using \myautoref{sec:vis} and \myautoref{sec:vis}, but \myautoref{localsection}

\section{Local section}\label{localsection}
\end{document}
```

**extfile.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\section{A section} \label{sec:vis}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: a small addendum: instead of doing nothing if the label is nowhere defined, one might use `\@ifundefined{r@#2}{\refdangling{#2}}{\autoref{#2}}` with `\newcommand{\refdangling}[1]{{\color{magenta}\IDontKnow\{#1\}}}` or just use `\autoref{#2}` without checking `r@#2`