# Adding pagenumber to crossreference command

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, page-numbering

in "[making external references stick out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271860/making-external-references-stick-out/271876#271876)"

I found the new command written below very helpful. Although I would like to add a pagenumber to the external file in the \myautoref command, and can't seem to find any topics in the forums.

Can anybody help with adding a pagenumber reference?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}

\usepackage{hyperref} 

\externaldocument[A-]{extfile}  %(A)
\makeatletter

\newcommand{\myautoref}[2][A-]{%
  \@ifundefined{r@#1#2}{% Nope A-#2 isn't there
    \@ifundefined{r@#2}{%
    }{%
      \autoref{#2}%
    }%
  }{%
    {\pending{#1#2}}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\pending}[1]{\color{red}\autoref{#1} from "file.tex"}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
Using \myautoref{sec:vis} and \myautoref{sec:vis}, but \myautoref{localsection}

\section{Local section}\label{localsection}
\end{document}
```

**extfile.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\section{A section} \label{sec:vis}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\pageref`???? (minimal comment length)

Comment: I remember this solution ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, i wanted to comment on the earlier post, but didn't have the 'privilege' so I had to make it a new question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the macro `\pageref` inside your definition of `\pending`.

Incidentally, if you want to use `\autoref` to cross-reference items located in externally compiled files, you should load `hyperref` in the external files. Thus, `extfile.tex` should look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}  % <- new
\begin{document}
\section{A section} \label{sec:vis}
\end{document}
```

The main file could then look like this:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\externaldocument[A-]{extfile}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=red]{hyperref} 

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myautoref}[2][A-]{%
  \@ifundefined{r@#1#2}{% Nope A-#2 isn't there
    \@ifundefined{r@#2}{}{\autoref{#2}}%
  }{{\pending{#1#2}}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\pending}[1]{\color{red}\autoref{#1} on page~\pageref{#1} of ``file.tex''}

\begin{document}
Using \myautoref{sec:vis}, but \autoref{localsection}.

\section{Local section} \label{localsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mark - Glad to learn it works. Don't forget to accept the answer you believe to be most helpful. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As already suggested: `\pageref` or in an expandable context: `\getpagerefnumber` (requires `refcount`) package.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}

\externaldocument[A-]{extfile}  %(A)

\usepackage{hyperref} 

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\myautoref}[2][A-]{%
  \@ifundefined{r@#1#2}{% Nope A-#2 isn't there
    \@ifundefined{r@#2}{%
    }{%
      \autoref{#2} on page \pageref{#2}%
    }%
  }{%
    {\pending{#1#2}}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\pending}[1]{\color{red}\autoref{#1} from "file.tex" on page \getpagerefnumber{#1}}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
Using \myautoref{sec:vis} and \myautoref{sec:vis}, but \myautoref{localsection}

\section{Local section}\label{localsection}
\end{document}
```

In order to prevent `autoref` from complaining, adding `\usepackage{hyperref}` to the external file is recommended:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]
\section{A section} \label{sec:vis}
\end{document}
```